# Javascript making submit button non functional

Tags: javascript, html

I am using velocity scripting for a web page.I have a hidden field that I am populating with value entered with the value entered in another field ( JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x1bdgvyt/). when I try to implement the javascript with my existing code base the submit button doesn not function anymore. IIt works fine before I plug in the JS. Clicking on it doesnt do anything. I am not sure what is wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

HTML submit button code

```
<div>   
  <ul class="action">
<li> <input class="Orange_button" type="submit" value="Start my free trial"> 
     <div class="sub-text"> TEXT TEXT TEXT </div> </li>

    <div class="column"> 
 <li>
    <span > | </span><br/>
    <span > or </span><br/>
    <span > | </span>
  </li>
   </div>
<li> <input class="green_button" type="submit" value="Buy it now"> 
     <div class="sub-text"> TEXT TEXT TEXT </div> </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Java script code

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
$('[name="retype-email"]').val($('[name="email"]').val());
 e.preventDefault()

});
```

Comment: I downvoted this question, because the sole purpose of this script seems to be to block the default action of the submit button. In other words, RTM.

Comment: So why need a submit button in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By including `e.preventDefault()` you're blocking the default behavior of the button. Remove it.

Comment: Thanks, That did work in making button functional. But I ran into another issue.  I am trying to populate a hidden field with the value of a field in the form. When I tried it standalone in fiddle it worked. But, when I try to do it with my code, the it doesn't seem to happen. http://jsfiddle.net/x1bdgvyt/

Comment: There must be some other piece of code that is having an effect on it then. Please create another Fiddle that contains everything.